# iMessage with iPad and iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, ipad, messages

My iPad was linked with my iPhone with iMessaging.  If I change my apple ID on my iPhone, will that prevent my messages from appearing on my iPad?  Or will it automatically change the account info on the iPad too?  Someone has my iPad and I don't want them to see my iMessages as I get them on my iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the Apple ID from the iPad, and your iMessages will not show up there